# Enabling WiFi on ASUS Laptop

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, laptop

I have purchased a new ASUS's model x550LD. I have installed Windows 8 Pro. I am trying to enable Wi-Fi by pressing fn+f2 . But it doesn't switch it on. Anyone have an idea ? 
Also I have installed all the drivers required.

**Update:**
As @Bob suggested I have checked Wireless settings in metro settings, there it is saying:
***No wireless devices are available.***
But I installed the WLan driver already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution finally. I had to download the wlan software from ASUS support site. There I had to choose operating system `Windows 7` , Because `Windows 8` was not listed there instead there was `Windows 8.1`. With `Windows 7's WLAN_Atheros_Win7_64_VER1000285` software, I am able to run Wi-Fi.

Comment: FYI you're eligible for free upgrade to Windows 8.1. And even without it, Windows 8.1 driver would probably work on Win8. But all that stuff aside, the driver should come preinstalled on the laptop - you may have removed it accidentally.

Comment: curious that it didn't detect it in device manager when I asked on chat. Usually those devices are detected at least as unknown devices, and/or you get a generic driver downloaded if you have any network connection at all.

Comment: @gronostaj My ASUS's laptop comes up with Windows 8.1 drivers , when I was trying to install on Windows 8 Pro, was getting not compatible error. And yes, It was DOS on my laptop.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Yes, you're right. I dint check that previously. When you said to check, I checked for any WLAN driver, but dint notice of Unknown drivers. When I did, all I had to do, is to install the driver and all became well.

Answer (score 3):

Its entirely possible your wifi adaptor is quite simply entirely dead on arrival - check device manager - if its not there, call tech support. As it is a  *new* laptop, your best bet is to get it looked at/checked by asus's local tech support.